# SQL Server TSQL: Put Subsequent (date) rows into bins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have following table:

```
id    insertDate
1     2015-01-01
22    2015-01-02
43    2015-01-03
46    2015-01-06
124   2015-01-07
```

In the end i want to have a possiblity to group the rows that differ exaclty in one day so in that case

```
id    insertDate    groups
1     2015-01-01    1
22    2015-01-02    1
43    2015-01-03    1
46    2015-01-06    2
124   2015-01-07    2
```

How is this possible? I bet it is some fancy window function usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "gaps and islands" problem.

One approach is below. This works on SQL Server 2005+. I have assumed that `insertDate` is unique as per your example data.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [insertDate]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Grp
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT [id],
       [insertDate],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Grp) AS Grp
FROM   CTE
```

Comment: thanks it s unique. now that i see the solution it seems easier than i thought it is.

Comment: @tuxmania - Yes once you know the "trick" it is quite simple. Itzik Ben Gan writes a lot about this type of requirement.